# ESP8266 Websockets problem

Tags: esp8266

I am trying to set up a network of 4 esp8266 programmed via the Arduino IDE. The Network will have 1 server (esp8266 running in AP mode) and 3 clients (esp8266 running in STA mode). I would like to do two things on the network.

1. Each client signals the server when a certain event happens (event is different for each client) and
2. Server broadcasts a byte of data to ALL clients on a regular basis (e.g. 1 second)

I have adapted various code to come up with the following (most examples I have seen do not use a standalone server).

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WebSocketsServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <ESP8266mDNS.h>
#include <Hash.h>

#define USE_SERIAL Serial

const char *ssid = "MyNetwork";
const char *password = "MyPassword";

unsigned long last_10sec = 0;
unsigned int counter = 0;

ESP8266WebServer server(80);

WebSocketsServer webSocket = WebSocketsServer(81);

void webSocketEvent(uint8_t num, WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {

    switch(type) {
        case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[%u] Disconnected!\n", num);
            break;
        case WStype_CONNECTED: {
            IPAddress ip = webSocket.remoteIP(num);
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[%u] Connected from %d.%d.%d.%d url: %s\n", num, ip[0], ip[1], ip[2], ip[3], payload);
            // send message to client
            webSocket.sendTXT(num, "Connected");
            }
            break;
        case WStype_TEXT:
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[%u] get Text: %s\n", num, payload);
            break;
    }

}

void setup() {
    WiFi.disconnect();
    USE_SERIAL.begin(115200);
    USE_SERIAL.println();

    for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
        USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\n", t);
        USE_SERIAL.flush();
        delay(1000);
    }

    WiFi.softAP(ssid, password,10,false,8); // setup AP on channel 10 and set 8 possible connections

    IPAddress myIP = WiFi.softAPIP();
    USE_SERIAL.print("AP IP address: ");
    USE_SERIAL.println(myIP);

    // start webSocket server
    USE_SERIAL.println("start websockets");
    webSocket.begin();
    webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
    USE_SERIAL.println("websockets started");

    server.on("/", []() {
      // send index.html
        server.send(200, "text/html", "<html><head><script>var connection = new WebSocket('ws://'+location.hostname+':81/', ['arduino']);connection.onopen = function () {  connection.send('Connect ' + new Date()); }; connection.onerror = function (error) {    console.log('WebSocket Error ', error);};connection.onmessage = function (e) {  console.log('Server: ', e.data);};function sendRGB() {  var r = parseInt(document.getElementById('r').value).toString(16);  var g = parseInt(document.getElementById('g').value).toString(16);  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('b').value).toString(16);  if(r.length < 2) { r = '0' + r; }   if(g.length < 2) { g = '0' + g; }   if(b.length < 2) { b = '0' + b; }   var rgb = '#'+r+g+b;    console.log('RGB: ' + rgb); connection.send(rgb); }</script></head><body>LED Control:<br/><br/>R: <input id=\"r\" type=\"range\" min=\"0\" max=\"255\" step=\"1\" oninput=\"sendRGB();\" /><br/>G: <input id=\"g\" type=\"range\" min=\"0\" max=\"255\" step=\"1\" oninput=\"sendRGB();\" /><br/>B: <input id=\"b\" type=\"range\" min=\"0\" max=\"255\" step=\"1\" oninput=\"sendRGB();\" /><br/></body></html>");
    });
    USE_SERIAL.println("start server");
    server.begin();

    USE_SERIAL.println("end setup and goto main loop");
}

void loop() {
    unsigned long t = millis();
   //;
    server.handleClient();

    if((t - last_10sec) > 30000) {
        counter++;
        bool ping = (counter % 2);
        int i = webSocket.connectedClients(ping);
        USE_SERIAL.printf("%d Connected websocket clients ping: %d\n", i, ping);
        last_10sec = millis();
    }
}
```

client code is

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>

#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFiMulti.h>

#include <WebSocketsClient.h>

#include <Hash.h>

const char *ssid = "MyNetwork";
const char *password = "MyPassword";
bool isConnected = false;

ESP8266WiFiMulti WiFiMulti;
WebSocketsClient webSocket;

#define USE_SERIAL Serial
#define MESSAGE_INTERVAL 10000
#define HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL 15000
uint64_t messageTimestamp = 0;
uint64_t heartbeatTimestamp = 0;

void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {

  switch(type) {
    case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] Disconnected!\n");
      isConnected=false;
      break;
    case WStype_CONNECTED: {
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] Connected to url: %s\n", payload);
      isConnected = true;
      // send message to server when Connected
      webSocket.sendTXT("Connected");
    }
      break;
    case WStype_TEXT:
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] get text: %s\n", payload);

      // send message to server
      // webSocket.sendTXT("message here");
      break;
    case WStype_BIN:
      USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] get binary length: %u\n", length);
      hexdump(payload, length);

      // send data to server
      // webSocket.sendBIN(payload, length);
      break;
/*        case WStype_PING:
            // pong will be send automatically
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] get ping\n");
            break;
        case WStype_PONG:
            // answer to a ping we send
            USE_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] get pong\n");
            break;
    }*/
  }
}

void setup() {

  USE_SERIAL.begin(115200);

  //Serial.setDebugOutput(true);
  USE_SERIAL.setDebugOutput(true);

  USE_SERIAL.println();
  USE_SERIAL.println();
  USE_SERIAL.println();

  for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
    USE_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\n", t);
    USE_SERIAL.flush();
    delay(1000);
  }
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 // was WiFiMulti.addAP("SSID", "passpasspass");

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    USE_SERIAL.printf(".");
  }

  USE_SERIAL.println("start websocket");
  // server address, port and URL
  webSocket.begin("192.168.4.1", 81, "/");

  // event handler
  webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
  delay(10000);
  // try ever 5000 again if connection has failed
  webSocket.setReconnectInterval(5000);
  USE_SERIAL.println("end of setup. Goto Main loop");
}

void loop() {
  webSocket.loop();
    if(isConnected) {
        USE_SERIAL.printf("Connected\n");
        uint64_t now = millis();

        if(now - messageTimestamp > MESSAGE_INTERVAL) {
            messageTimestamp = now;
            USE_SERIAL.printf("send message\n");
            // example socket.io message with type "messageType" and JSON payload
            webSocket.sendTXT("42[\"messageType\",{\"greeting\":\"hello\"}]");
        }
        if((now - heartbeatTimestamp) > HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL) {
            heartbeatTimestamp = now;
             USE_SERIAL.printf("heartbeat\n");
            // socket.io heartbeat message
            webSocket.sendTXT("2");
        }
    }
    else
    {
      USE_SERIAL.printf("not connected\n");
      delay(10000);
    }
}
```

The debug output for server is

```cpp
19:38:30.671 -> SDK:2.2.1(cfd48f3)/Core:2.5.2=20502000/lwIP:STABLE-2_1_2_RELEASE/glue:1.1-7-g82abda3/BearSSL:a143020
19:38:30.671 -> 
19:38:30.671 -> [SETUP] BOOT WAIT 4...
19:38:31.657 -> [SETUP] BOOT WAIT 3...
19:38:32.689 -> [SETUP] BOOT WAIT 2...
19:38:33.673 -> [SETUP] BOOT WAIT 1...
19:38:34.657 -> [AP] softap config unchanged
19:38:34.704 -> AP IP address: 192.168.4.1
19:38:34.704 -> start websockets
19:38:34.704 -> [WS-Server] Server Started.
19:38:34.704 -> websockets started
19:38:34.704 -> start server
19:38:34.704 -> end setup and goto main loop
19:38:58.354 -> wifi evt: 7
19:38:58.495 -> wifi evt: 7
19:38:58.635 -> wifi evt: 7
19:39:00.606 -> 0 Connected websocket clients ping: 1
19:39:00.935 -> add 1
19:39:00.935 -> aid 1
19:39:00.935 -> station: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx join, AID = 1
19:39:00.935 -> wifi evt: 5
19:39:01.075 -> wifi evt: 9
19:39:03.102 -> wifi evt: 7
19:39:03.257 -> wifi evt: 7
19:39:03.377 -> wifi evt: 7
19:39:03.527 -> wifi evt: 7
19:39:03.837 -> wifi evt: 7
19:39:30.567 -> 0 Connected websocket clients ping: 0
19:40:00.595 -> 0 Connected websocket clients ping: 1
19:40:30.573 -> 0 Connected websocket clients ping: 0
19:41:00.577 -> 0 Connected websocket clients ping: 1
```

and debug output for client is

```cpp
19:13:45.235 -> SDK:2.2.1(cfd48f3)/Core:2.5.2=20502000/lwIP:STABLE-2_1_2_RELEASE/glue:1.1-7-g82abda3/BearSSL:a143020
19:13:45.235 -> 
19:13:45.235 -> 
19:13:45.235 -> 
19:13:45.235 -> [SETUP] BOOT WAIT 4...
19:13:46.267 -> [SETUP] BOOT WAIT 3...
19:13:46.642 -> wifi evt: 2
19:13:47.251 -> [SETUP] BOOT WAIT 2...
19:13:48.095 -> scandone
19:13:49.032 -> state: 0 -> 2 (b0)
19:13:49.032 -> [SETUP] BOOT WAIT 1...
19:13:49.032 -> state: 2 -> 3 (0)
19:13:49.079 -> state: 3 -> 5 (10)
19:13:49.079 -> add 0
19:13:49.079 -> aid 1
19:13:49.079 -> cnt 
19:13:49.079 -> 
19:13:49.079 -> connected with MyNetwork, channel 10
19:13:49.079 -> dhcp client start...
19:13:49.079 -> wifi evt: 0
19:13:49.219 -> ip:192.168.4.2,mask:255.255.255.0,gw:192.168.4.1
19:13:49.219 -> wifi evt: 3
19:13:50.626 -> ....scandone
19:13:52.641 -> .start websocket
19:13:59.062 -> pm open,type:2 0
19:14:02.624 -> end of setup. Goto Main loop
19:14:02.624 -> [WS-Client] connect ws...
19:14:02.624 -> [hostByName] Host: 192.168.4.1 is a IP!
19:14:02.671 -> [WS-Client] connected to 192.168.4.1:81.
19:14:02.671 -> [WS-Client][sendHeader] sending header...
19:14:02.671 -> [WS-Client][sendHeader] handshake GET / HTTP/1.1
19:14:02.671 -> Host: 192.168.4.1:81
19:14:02.671 -> Connection: Upgrade
19:14:02.671 -> Upgrade: websocket
19:14:02.671 -> Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
19:14:02.671 -> Sec-WebSocket-Key: 8L/m+WcjssjBS/Sa8a0Qvg==
19:14:02.671 -> Sec-WebSocket-Protocol: arduino
19:14:02.671 -> Origin: file://
19:14:02.671 -> User-Agent: arduino-WebSocket-Client
19:14:02.671 -> 
19:14:02.671 -> [write] n: 241 t: 17509
19:14:02.671 -> [WS-Client][sendHeader] sending header... Done (23209us).
19:14:02.671 -> not connected
19:14:12.661 -> not connected
19:14:22.659 -> not connected
19:14:32.664 -> not connected
19:14:42.687 -> not connected
19:14:52.671 -> not connected
19:15:02.657 -> not connected
19:15:12.692 -> not connected
19:15:22.677 -> not connected
19:15:32.674 -> not connected
```

I am reading this as the client connecting to the AP but not connecting via websockets. Can anyone assist?

Comment: The server you set as `server(80)` and the client you set as `webSocket.begin(ip, 81,...)` .why you do that? Try to use same port.