# Understanding WiFi.printDiag(Serial)

Tags: esp8266, wifi

I am having difficulty with setting up websockets using the Arduino IDE with an ESP8266 [ESP8266 Websockets problem](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/66704/esp8266-websockets-problem) and I have added WiFi.printDiag(Serial) to the main loop of my code. The Output I get (with my comments added) is

```
14:34:03.325 -> DIAGNOSTIC INFO   Debug Comment I added
14:34:03.325 -> 
14:34:03.325 -> Mode: AP          Presume this means ESP is in AP mode
14:34:03.325 -> PHY mode:N        XXX
14:34:03.325 -> Channel: 1        Presume this means AP is on channel 1
14:34:03.325 -> AP id: 0          XXX
14:34:03.325 -> Status: 255       XXX
14:34:03.325 -> Auto connect: 1   XXX
14:34:03.325 -> SSID (0):         XXX
14:34:03.325 -> Passphrase (0):   XXX
14:34:03.325 -> BSSID set: 0      XXX

The AP is setup and I can see it in WiFI Analyser on my phone.
Is there a reference somewhere that explains the lines with XXX in them, or can
someone suggest meanings? Thanks
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Mode: AP

In access point mode. Can also be STA or STA+AP for Station or dual role modes.

> PHY mode:N

Physical interface mode. At the moment it's in 802.11n mode. Depends on the AP you are connecting to if any.

> Channel: 1

Which WiFi channel you are communicating on

All the following are meaningless in AP mode. They only pertain to STA mode:

> AP id: 0

Internal ID of the access point you are connecting to, if any.

> Status: 255

Connection status

> Auto connect: 1

Automatically connect to an access point.

> SSID (0):

Name of the access point currently connected to.

> Passphrase (0):

Password used to connect to the current access point

> BSSID set: 0

BSSID (kind of like the MAC address) of the access point connected to.

As you can see, much of it is meaningless for access point mode, since it mostly is to do with connecting the ESP8266 to an existing network.  In AP mode there's not a lot of debugging information you can get - "is it running?" is really all there is.